# Get list of liferay users having action permission

Tags: java, permissions, liferay

I want to get a list of liferay users having specific action permission. I tried with the PermissionChecker but it works with the current user not the other liferay users. Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

There is no single API method which could let you achieve this. You need to get know which role is connected with given permission in first place. Then just check for users having given roles.

My suggestion to achieve it is:

1. First of all look for all resource permissions you are interested about  using method **ResourcePermissionLocalServiceUtil.getResourcePermissions(...)**
2. Then having list of **ResourcePermission** objects you can check their roleId using method getRoleId() on each object. Store these ids.
3. Now having given **roleIds** you can easly look for Users using **UserLocalServiceUtil.getRoleUsers(...)**

For details how Liferay is storing permissions you can check this article https://www.liferay.com/web/mohit.soni/blog/-/blogs/deep-dive-in-roles-and-permissions

Comment: Let me know if you need any help.

Comment: Hi tomic; can you please contact me on my email i have some confusion :(..My email is :aymen.debbabi@esprit.tn .Thanks a lot.